# An error was received while processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How can I find out more about that error?

This is what's shown in the log:

```
Processing TrendsController#update (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-04 17:24:18) [PUT] Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update", "authenticity_token"=>"WZpPerl3dV+edWXhxLiBlNfv3KTFb0fNLVkhF3ZMNXA=", "id"=>"1", "trend"=>{"title"=>"bluiz", "description"=>"uzgz", "image"=>#}}

[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h "C:/Windows/Temp/stream20110104-3660-1j1ap8i-0.jpg[0]" 2>NUL

[paperclip] convert "C:/Windows/Temp/stream20110104-3660-1j1ap8i-0.jpg[0]" -resize "100x140>" "C:/Windows/Temp/stream20110104-3660-1j1ap8i-020110104-3660-rmkivh-0" 2>NUL

[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #
```

Comment: Try to run that same `convert` command from the command line to see if it produces better error message.

Comment: does it work in console? additionally, put a breakpoint in an before save of your model and try to run the command from there.  that way your env variables will be the same as during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put the PATH-entries for ImageMagick and FFMPEG before system32 in the environment-variables, because it tried to use Windows' own convert-command.